# How can i change the theme for a site from front end in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

In my wordpress site i have 10 themes. I need to change the themes by clicking the link from  the front end site.(Normally we change the themes in admin login). I need to change the themes without login in to the admin panel.

Is that possible?..

Comment: when you say "I need to..." who is "I"? Is that a user with the appropriate permissions for theme changing, or do you want to allow users without permissions to change the theme? If the latter are they registered, logged-in users? And when you say "change the theme" do you really want them to be able to change the theme for all users, or just what they see?

Comment: @cori i mean anyone can change the theme by clicking the theme name which is going to be displayed in the site.

Comment: and you want them to change it for everyone, not just for themselves?

Comment: also, for what it's worth, this is probably WP-specific enough to belong on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How different are the themes from each other? If page templates and all are the same in each theme and you're essentially only changing the style sheet, then you can incorporate different sheets in one theme and switch theme with the help of a cookie or session variable. If a whole lot of other crap changes as well, i'd go with the plugin proposed by Virgil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the [Theme Switcher plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher/) and it will print out a list of your themes in your sidebar and users can click the links to make the switch. See more about [Theme Switching in the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Switching).

Comment: Thank you very much.But once i change the theme,from that theme  i can't change to other theme.

Comment: You're welcome, simply add <?php wp_theme_switcher(); ?> to the side bar of each theme and it will work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you are not administrator or permitted by administrator then it is fully impossible .If you are permitted to change then simple go to dashboard then go theme option and change it.

Comment: This question was asked quite a while ago -- consider checking out some more recent submissions!